# Django Tastypie - Filter for "OR" Operation

Tags: django, tastypie

I have two groups "Normal" & "Admin" in Django with a different set of Permission sets.

I am trying to filter the Users based on the Permissions, I need to check if user is present in either one of the groups.

I know that we can check if a user is in one or more group by the following

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User, Group

User.objects.filter(groups__name=['Normal','Admin'])
```

The above does an AND Operation. Is there anything that can used to check if the user is in either one of the Groups ??

I am aware that there is a `apply_filters` method that we can override.

But I am just checking out if is there something else that is straight forward for a simple Operation like "OR" ??.

Any reference links is also appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure but maybe this will be helpful:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects[enter link description here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects)

Comment: Yes I have seen this Q Objects .. But I was wondering why Tastypie after being such a nice plugin .. hasn't come up with a simple OR filter ... Thanks anyway ..